# SpotifyAPI.Web nuget package. How do I convert IPlayableItem to FullTrack?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget-package

I'm making a spotify application and using the SpotifyAPI.Web nuget package, but when you get a track it's in the form of IPlayableItem. How do I convert IPlayableItem to FullTrack?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this whatsoever, I have tried the only way I know to; try to create a playlist object, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IPlayableItem` can be either a track or an episode, so you'll have to check if it's a track before you can access the `FullTrack` properties.

Simply do a check with `is` operator to find out!

```
if (item.Track is FullTrack track) {
    // All FullTrack properties are available
    Console.WriteLine(track.Name);
}
```

or

```
if (item.Track is FullTrack) {
    FullTrack track = (FullTrack) item.Track;
    // All FullTrack properties are available
    Console.WriteLine(track.Name);
}
```

Comment: It shows an error when using that code bit; the object I'm trying to get the track or episode of an an IPlayableItem.

Comment: Well, "track" is not a valid member of "IPlayableItem" (That's what the error means.)       I have a single IPlayableItem object from: var item = player.GetCurrentPlayback().Result.Item; btw package version is 6.1.0

Comment: Have you tried checking if the `item` is a `FullTrack`? The above code is literary from the documentation for [`IPlayableItem`](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/docs/next/iplayableitem)

Comment: so.. I did:

if (item.Item is FullTrack track) {
    
    Console.WriteLine(track.Name);
}             I'm gonna  test it to see if it works now.